# Facing Issue in uploading image byte stream blob store via cloudstorage using python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

> Here is the code that I'm using to upload image (sent by mobile device in API call). I get the Blob key
>   after upload but when I check the image in cloud-storage, I get error
>   saying image cannot be displayed as it contains error.

```
gcs.open(filename,'w',content_type='image/jpeg')
gcs_file.write(data.encode('utf-8'))
gcs_file.close()    
blobstore_filename = '/gs' + filename
blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)
```

Comment: I do not understand your code. 1) Show how you get "data" for your line-2 code. 2) And you say: "I get the blobkey after upload", but you create the blobkey using create_gs_key in line-5??

Comment: The data is received  from mobile devices via an API call, here i have shown a part of the code and i am creating the blob key in line 5 only.

Comment: I still do not understand it. Which API call, which returns utf-8 for an image?